# CloudFront rate limit rule doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront distribution for an EC2 HTTP server. I created a rate limit for my CloudFront distribution [using WAF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/APIReference/API_CreateRateBasedRule.html). In theory no IP address should be able to send more than 2,000 requests in any 5 minute period. But this just doesn't seem to work. I fired off 10,000 concurrent requests from my laptop (using a Go program) in <1 minute and all of them got through. I know they are reaching the EC2 origin because my HTTP server keeps a counter for requests.

Strangely, the WAF dashboard even recognizes that traffic exceeded the 5 minute limit:

[image]

Yet no IP blocking took place:
[image]

And my EC2 server registered all 10,000 hits.

Am I missing some configuration subtlety? Or is there meant to be a long delay between when CloudFront registers the traffic spike and when it implements the IP block?

EDIT:
A config picture:
[image]

Comment: Drop your request rate to about 500 per minute and observe what happens after ~5 minutes.  Let it run for at least 10.

Comment: I ran ~1200 per minute for 10 minutes and all 13,000 requests got through. Is it safe to conclude that there's some bug in my configuration, or could this actually be intended firewall behavior?

Comment: I would say there's a misconfiguration.  I tested this a while back, and if I remember right, my result was getting blocked after 5 minutes.

Comment: Verify that in the Web ACL you set the Action to Block, not Count.  Count just counts.  Also verify that there isn't another rule higher on the list that is set to Allow. (Although now I'm not sure whether that matters.  I think it does.)

Comment: Gotcha. Good to hear that it's an issue on my end at least. Action is block, and I don't have any other rules (set up is very minimal, I am just testing this functionality). Question edited with picture of rule.

Comment: @rampatowl Were you ever able to figure this out? I'm running into the same behavior. In my case I have the limit set the to lowest, 100, however I can easily send 1000+ requests with no blocks. It does block some requests, but the logic isn't very clear

Comment: Hi alan, unfortunately I never figured this out.

Comment: Same problem, some blocking occurred but I was able to send 20000 request in one minute only 88 got blocked when rule is only 100 requests are allowed. Did someone find any solution @Michael-sqlbot

Answer (score 2):

You probably already figured this out, but... you have to specifically select the `AWS WAF Web ACL` that contains the rate-limit-rule in your CloudFront distribution. You can do this in the `Distribution Settings`-page of your CloudFront distribution (second item - a dropdown with the label `AWS WAF Web ACL`).

If you don't, the two aren't connected together, which might explain why your request aren't blocked when you expect them to be blocked.